# in what directory is logins.json?

Tags: login, 20.10

Following updates to Ubuntu and Firefox, all my site login data has disappeared. A web search suggested that the logins.json file had been corrupted or that its file name had been changed to logins.json.corrupted. So my question is, in what Ubuntu 20.10 directory would I find the file logins.json?

Answer (score 1):

You can find it on your system by running the `find` command from your home `~` folder:

```
find . -type f -name logins*
```

Example:

```
~$ find . -type f -name logins*
./.mozilla/firefox/k2laopy5.default-release/logins.json
./.mozilla/firefox/k2laopy5.default-release/logins-backup.json
./.mozilla/firefox/btjnapfh.default-release-2/logins.json
./.mozilla/firefox/btjnapfh.default-release-2/logins-backup.json
find: ‘./.gvfs’: Permission denied
./.steam/debian-installation/tenfoot/resource/styles/login/loginstyles.css
```

As we can see mine is found in `./.mozilla/firefox/k2laopy5.default-release/` or `./.mozilla/firefox/btjnapfh.default-release-2/`

Hope this helps!